# Xcode 6.1 problems

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm having troubles with IB in Xcode 6.1 running on OSX Mavericks 10.9.5 (macbook air early 2014, 128gb storage, 4gb memory).

When resizing certain controls in IB, this happens - my container segue just points out to the middle of nowhere and the control disappears.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When you run the app and follow that segue, does it open a portal to another dimension???

Comment: Yeah! I just met Obi-Wan Kenobi in Coruscant!

Comment: @IanMacDonald the lightsabers are on sale, want me to get you one? Only 9.99$